# How to get rid of the icon shadow on a tab bar

Tags: xcode, icons, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a tab bar application and on each icon on my tab bar there is a shadow:

[image]

The code to apply the icon is:

[image]

I am wondering what i should do.